# Аномальный switch в Ruby

Tags: ruby

Есть следующий код:

```
x = 16
puts case x.class
     when Fixnum
       "fix"
     else
       "other"
     end
```

И результатом будет `"other"`

Но если написать:

```
x = 16
puts case x
     when Fixnum
       "fix"
     else
       "other"
     end
```

То ответом будет `"fix"`. Почему так? Ведь `x.class` просто возвращает константу Fixnum, почему бы ему не вернуть в первом случае `"fix"`?

Ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается, есть специальный метод case-equality (`===`) и каждый класс переопределяет его, как хочет. По умолчанию, этот метод (class-method) проверяет принадлежность аргумента к классу. `Regexp` переопределяет его поведение как `match`, а для `Array` (`===`) это синоним для `member?` и `included?`.

Это очень удобно использовать для своих классов.

В случае `Fixnum`, дополнительно определяется instance метод для прямого сравнения чисел.

```
Fixnum === 16 # => true, принадлежит к классу
16 === Fixnum # => false, переопределено для прямого (==) сравнения
```

Я ожидал от case-выражения прямого сравнения (`==`), и поэтому поведение казалось аномальным.

Comment: @ХэшКод Примите мой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Нет ничего аномального, x.class выведет результат типа class

```
x = 16
y = x.class
puts y.class
```

Этот код покажет "fix":

```
x = 16
puts case x.class
    when Fixnum.class
        "fix"
    else
        "other"
end
```

Comment: Fixnum.class вернёт Class. x.class вернёт Fixnum. Они не равны.

Comment: Ошибочка: Fixnum и Class

Comment: контр-пример:

<pre>
x = 16
puts case x.class
     when String.class
       "string"
     when Fixnum.class
       "fixnum"
     else
       "other"
     end

# => string
</pre>